# How to center dialog on screen in QtQuick Controls 2?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

All my dialogs appear on the top left corner of screen instead of the center.

What is the best way to let the dialogs be placed automatically correct?

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        showMessageBox('Hey this actually works!');
    }

    function showMessageBox(message) {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("MessageDialog.qml")
        if(component.status == Component.Ready) {
            var dialog = component.createObject(mainWindow)

            dialog.title = qsTr("Information")
            dialog.text = message

            dialog.open()
        } else
            console.error(component.errorString())
    }
}
```

With a very simple **MessageDialog.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Dialog {
    standardButtons: DialogButtonBox.Ok

    property alias text : textContainer.text

    Text {
        id: textContainer

        anchors.fill: parent

        horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignTop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation for Qt5 hints, that the [`Dialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-dialog.html) is a descendent of [`Popup`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html) which has [**`x/y`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#x-prop)-coordinates.

I think those would be a good start to position it.

To your avail:

- `parent.width` - which should be the width of your window
- `width` - which should be your `Dialog`s width
- `parent.height`
- `height`

Calculate the right positions, and you should be fine.

With this you can create a new *base class* `CenteredDialog.qml`

```
Dialog {
    x: (parent.width - width) / 2
    y: (parent.height - height) / 2
}
```

and then use `CenteredDialog` instead of `Dialog` all the time.

Further, for *dynamic instantiation* you might declare the `Component` in the file, and only set the properties upon instantiation using the `component.createObject(parentObject, { property1Name : property1Value, property2Name : property2Value ... })` syntax.

*Note* Qt 5.12 and higher can use `anchors.centerIn`, see answer from @lateus

Comment: Ok, I changed to `QtQuick 2.7`. I was looking for a solution where I dont have to care about widths and heights. Would it be bad practice to use the old `QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2`?

Comment: It depends on your usecase. The problem for me is, that `Dialog` is introduced with `QtQuick 2.8`, so I could only evaluate the underlying `Popup`.

Comment: Are you sure? I am the `Dialog` from here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-dialog.html So no `QtQuick 2.8` needed, right?

Comment: Right at the top of this page you have a small table which states an *import statement*, a *since* (Qt5.8) and a *inherits*

Comment: Ah ok, so does `Qt 5.8` mean `QtQuick 2.8`? I did not know the connection.

Comment: Since qt has been progressing, I think this answer needs an update (see answer from @lateus)

Answer (score 7):

As of Qt 5.12 you can use `anchors.centerIn` attached property.

```
Dialog {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    // ...
}
```

Then it will be centered on its parent. If you want it to be centered on its window, just set its parent to `Overlay.overlay`.

Comment: The Qt version detail here was super useful, as I'm trying to support a legacy Qt 5.11 build, which was throwing an error on my attempt to use this "new" feature.

Answer (score 6):

For a generic code which works anywhere, including out of Window/ApplicationWindow, you should use Overlay parent :

```
Dialog {
    parent: Overlay.overlay // <------- global Overlay object
    readonly property int margin: 16
    width: parent ? (parent.width / 2 - margin) : 128
    height: content.height + margin
    x: parent ? ((parent.width - width) / 2) : 0
    y: parent ? ((parent.height - height) / 2) : 0
    modal: true

   Label {
      id: content
      ...   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set x/y position (like derM said), but you have to recalculate every size change of ApplicationWindow!

Here is another solution:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        showMessageBox('Hey this actually works!');
    }

    Item {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: msgDialog.width
        height: msgDialog.height
        MessageDialog {
            id: msgDialog
            title: qsTr("Information")
            visible: false
        }
    }

    function showMessageBox(message) {
        msgDialog.text = message
        msgDialog.visible = true
    }
```

UPDATE: with dynamic instantiation:

```
 Item {
    id: dialogParent
    anchors.centerIn: parent
 }

 function showMessageBox(message) {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("MessageDialog.qml")
    if(component.status === Component.Ready) {
        var dialog = component.createObject(dialogParent)

        dialog.title = qsTr("Information")
        dialog.text = message
        dialog.open()

        dialogParent.width = dialog.width
        dialogParent.height = dialog.height
    } else {
        console.error(component.errorString())
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is there any disadvantage when I use `component.createObject`? I just wanted to avoid instantiating all my dialogs when I dont use them (yet).

Comment: No, but you have to change the size of the item with every instantiation. (I added this solution to my answer)

Comment: And you need to reparent and reposition the `Item` everytime... Otherwise your `Dialog` won't be in the top layer. Ideally the parent of the `Dialog` is [`ApplicationWindow.overlay`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html#attached-properties). You could, ofc create one Item in the `ApplicationWindow.overlay`-layer, and reuse this all the time, but then you are limited to one `Dialog` at a time. When you open another one, with a different size, close it thereafter, the right size won't be restored.

Comment: The dialog will be in a separate qml file and therefore the parent of `dialogParent` won't be the main window. I then tried setting `anchors.centerIn: ApplicationWindow.overlay` but this results in a error message: `Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling.`

Answer (score 0):

anchors.centerIn: Overlay.overlay